# Install QGIS Dev on Ubuntu or WSL

Tags: qgis, ubuntu, ubuntugis

I am using WSL (Ubuntu 18.04) on win 10 trying to install QGIS Dev.
I tried following the instructions here but got back the following message.

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done        
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created 
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
qgis : Depends: libqgis-3d3.17.0 but it is not going to be installed
Depends: libqgis-analysis3.17.0 but it is not going to be installed
Depends: libqgis-app3.17.0 but it is not going to be installed
Depends: libqgis-core3.17.0 but it is not going to be installed
Depends: libqgis-gui3.17.0 but it is not going to be installed
Depends: python3-qgis (= 1:3.17.0+git20201212+5deda1f456+28bionic) but it is not going to be installed
Depends: qgis-providers (= 1:3.17.0+git20201212+5deda1f456+28bionic) but it is not going to be installed
qgis-plugin-grass : Depends: qgis-provider-grass (= 1:3.17.0+git20201212+5deda1f456+28bionic) but it is not going to be installed
Depends: grass740
Depends: libqgis-app3.17.0 but it is not going to be installed
Depends: libqgis-core3.17.0 but it is not going to be installed
Depends: libqgis-gui3.17.0 but it is not going to be installed
Depends: libqgisgrass7-3.17.0 but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

This is the code I tried running:

```
sudo apt install gnupg software-properties-commonH
wget -qO - https://qgis.org/downloads/qgis-2020.gpg.key | sudo gpg --no-default-keyring --keyring gnupg-ring:/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/qgis-archive.gpg --import
sudo chmod a+r /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/qgis-archive.gpg 
sudo add-apt-repository "deb https://qgis.org/debian-nightly `lsb_release -c -s` main"
sudo apt update
sudo apt install qgis qgis-plugin-grass
```

Am I doing something wrong?
Do I need to use a virtual machine with a GUI instead of using WSL?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of the grass plugin, add python3-qgis to your installation.

If you run into further problems, try the qgis.org/ubuntugis-nightly bionic release. It contains newer versions of GDAL which might be necessary for the qgis dev packages.

Comment: I would really like to accept this, however this was a job for a former client and I no longer have any access to test your answer, if any third party could test this and get a confirmation this works on WSL I would be happy to accept this answer.